# vue router react on parent component using a modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vue-reactivity

Visit /parent page and Parent component is rendered,

Visit /parent/modal and the Child component is rendered (Opening a modal component),

Navigate back to /parent (Trying to render the updated data in the parent component) This is where I am stuck!

After saving the data, I'm tracking the route params, and the fetching the data using a function. However, the parent is not reactive.

I have to manually refresh or do add a location.reload() in the function to see the data change.

Why is the parent not reactive on router change?

I've setup a route watch:

```
'$route' (to, from) {
    this.fetchUpdate
}
```

- Did not work

However, in the vue.js documentation beforeRouteEnter & beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) is apparently the preferred method and the data still gets fetched like the watch, still, the parent is not reactive.

It works when I haven't set the route to be nested (/parent/child) however, then the "light box" effect won't be there and it looks like a full-size page load.

```
//Route Structure

{
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'dashboard',
    component: Dashboard,
    meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
    },
    children: [
        {
            path: 'modal',
            name: 'modal',
            component: Modal,
            meta: {
              requiresAuth: true
            }
        }
    ]
},

// Parent Structure

beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
        vm.fetchUpdate()
        next();
    })
},
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    firebaseDb.collection('post').where('post_id',
      '==', to.params.post_id).get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                next(vm => {
                  vm.post_id = doc.data().post_id
                  vm.title = doc.data().title
                  vm.paragraph = doc.data().paragraph
                })
            })
        })
}
,
```

We're just trying to get a Modal version of edit post to work as it's more user-friendly and we are just completely stuck

Let me know if you need more of the code structure

Answer (score 0):

Show full snippet of parent component, please.